# Is it me or yarn?

Tags: node.js, installation, yarnpkg, package-managers

`apt` works great for me. Rarely a problem and always easy to fix.

`conda` works great for me. Rarely a problem and always easy to fix.

I can't seem to get yarn to work...ever. Always some strange problem with node version or gyp libraries. Even when I get all of that fixed I get lots of warnings and then errors like

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/balter/.cache/yarn/v4/npm-tar-fs-1.16.3-966a628841da2c4010406a82167cbd5e0c72d509/node_modules/tar-fs/test/fixtures/a/hello.txt'".
```

Turns out if I run `yarn install` again there is a different file it can't find. Just for fun, I did

```
for i in {1..100}; do yarn install; done
```

Yup it errored on a different file every time, but never did "work."

Is it me, or is yarn just really fragile? If I want to install a package from github and the install instructions use yarn, is there a way around using yarn?

Also, no tag for "yarn"

Comment: Might be you. Try the same on a clean machine.

Comment: If by "clean machine" you mean removing all the node caches and yarn caches, I've done that. But my machine is my laptop, and I'm not going to wipe it just to install some package to try out (in this case, Theia IDE). I don't have to create "clean machines" for `apt` and `conda`.

Comment: You can create a clean machine in a VM (virtualbox, etc.). This way, your main dev machine is left intact.

Comment: Sure, if I'm into creating VMs every time I want to do something. I just want to run theia as a desktop ide on my laptop the way I would VSCode, Atom, Brackets, gedit, kate, etc. I can install any of those with one line no problem at all.

Comment: I'm simply suggesting a way to test the "yarn is fragile non-working garbage" hypothesis. For all we know, you _did_ mess up its installation somehow. If it was really that broken, there'd be a lot more noise about this (now that it manages js packages in rails too)

Comment: I see! That does make sense. I did try doing everything I did fresh, deleting all files and cache files. I also tried using a `conda` environment with its own `nodejs` and `yarn`. But that referred to the same `~/.cache/yarn` directory. I will give what you say a try.

Comment: I'm having this issue, I have tried yarn cache clean and clean builds on CI using latest Yarn to no avail. I'm forced to pull out yarn and rely on npm instead now due to this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in WSL one time and fix that using `yarn cache clean`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same frustrating and hard to debug error. The problem in my case seemed to be `yarn workspace` behaviour caused by different versions of the same dependency in different packages (specifically `ava` versions 2 and 3). Only once I'd upgraded all occurrences of `ava` to their latest did I stop getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same problem on Windows 10. I tried `yarn cache clen` because I saw that the `tar-fs` dependency was corrupted on disk going into the cache path (`C://...AppData/Local/Yarn/Cache/npm-tar-fs...`).

I saw that using `yarn cache clean` was deleting all cache files except for this one that was corrupted. I also tried deleting it manually and Windows wasn't allowing it.

So the solution was going into `cmd` and deleting it from there using the command `DEL /F /Q /A <File Path>`.

After that I ran `yarn install` again and it worked!